# How to create a page extension in Directus 7

Tags: content-management-system, directus

I have a working Directus CMS environment and would like to include some custom pages in there as well. According to the [documentation](https://docs.directus.io/extensions/pages.html)!, I "can build page modules for custom dashboards, reporting, point-of-sale systems, or anything else".

*The CMS is downloaded from directus, installed in localhost and then moved with FTP to the server as my client doesn't have terminal access allowed.*

I already tried the boilerplate from https://github.com/directus/extension-toolkit, created a vue page with it, ran npm to transpile it, but now I don't know where to put it. If I put it to public > extensions > custom > pages (I put here the whole created folder), it's not shown anywhere and I can't really find any tutorial or help on how to do it. Not even in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

You have to copy only the *dist* subdirectory of the extension to your server.

Example:

```sh
directus-extensions create page orders
directus-extensions build
rsync ./dist/ root@example.com:/var/www/directus/public/extensions/custom/pages/orders/
```

You should now see your page extension listed in the sidebar when you log in to your Directus app (provided your user role is configured to [display `extensions` in the sidebar](https://docs.directus.io/guides/roles.html#nav-override)).

[image]